# Unpivot with DayRange in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, unpivot

I have a table say,

[image]

and want to create another table using this one. Like

[image]

How can we do that, I tried Unpivot with Pivot Tables and Chart Wizard but looks like DayRange is a problem there.

Comment: yes, `DayRange` presents a problem, vba could work, but if you want a vba solution, you'll have to post the code you've tried to get it to work and tell us where it's not working. Also, in your 2nd example,. the last `DayRange` should say `Mon`, correct?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thanks for looking at this, I haven't tried VBA yet. But will give a shot to it.